# How to elegantly drop the identified records using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe like as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'subject_id': [101,102,103,201,202],
                  'test_id':[21,21,np.nan,24,25],
                  'test_name':['A','B',np.nan,'D','E'],
                  'invalid_condition':[0,0,0,0,1]})
```

I would like to identify the issues in the data based on below conditions and drop them

While I am able to identify them using the code below, I am not sure how to drop them

```
subject_with_no_test_info = len(df.groupby('subject_id').filter(lambda x: x['test_id'].count() == 0))*100/len(df)
test_id_diff_names = len(df.groupby('test_id').filter(lambda x: x['test_name'].nunique() > 1))*100/len(df)
invalid_condition = len(df[df['invalid_condition']==1])*100/len(df)
data_inconsistencies_df = pd.DataFrame([[subject_with_no_test_info,test_id_diff_names,invalid_condition]],columns = ['subject_with_no_test_info','test_id_diff_names','invalid_condition'])
```

This gives me an output like below

[image]

but now I want to drop those records which contribute to the `20%, 40% and 20%` under each column in the data_incosistencies_df?

Any elegant and efficient way to drop these records from the dataframe?

Comment: then instead of calculating percentage grab the indexes of rows where these 3 condition satisfies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
d1=df.groupby('subject_id').filter(lambda x: x['test_id'].count() == 0)
d2=df.groupby('test_id').filter(lambda x: x['test_name'].nunique() > 1)
d3=df[df['invalid_condition']==1]
#your conditions

data_inconsistencies_df = pd.DataFrame([[(len(d1)*100/len(df)),(len(d2)*100/len(df)),(len(d3)*100/len(df))]],columns = ['subject_with_no_test_info','test_id_diff_names','invalid_condition'])
#created dataframe to show percentages

d2=d2.drop_duplicates('test_id',keep='last')
          #^your sub condition
          #(We don't drop  101, because we keep = first of duplicate test ids)
to_drop=pd.concat([d1,d2,d3]).index
#concatinating 3 dataframes to grab the index of the rows which are going to drop
```

Finally:

```
df=df.drop(to_drop)
#dropping those indexes
```

Output of `df`:

```
  subject_id    test_id     test_name   invalid_condition
0   101         21.0            A           0
3   201         24.0            D           0
```

Output of `data_inconsistencies_df`:

```
  subject_with_no_test_info     test_id_diff_names  invalid_condition
0          20.0                         40.0            20.0
```